# How to get the equivalent of IS_MEMBER for a certain User using "Windows Login"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to check what database roles a Windows Auth user is in. We only use Windows Auth Login to verify the accessibility rights for certain users. We have some issues for members not having the right accessibility. I need to check for sure if the cause was in sql role membership or in our program itself. Thanks.

What our program looks is by running an SP with multiple IFs to check if what user member is

```
IF IS_MEMBER('Administration') = 1
SELECT 'Admin'

IF IS_MEMBER('Public') = 1
SELECT 'Public'
```

sort of like that.

What I need is to check if which member the user's logon is from. I know his login user but do not know how to test it. I think we are using SQL SERVER 2008 or higher.

---

If I run this query using my Windows Auth Login.

```
SELECT IS_MEMBER('Public')
```

I got result = 1 which means I am under Roles\Database Roles\Public

we have certain database roles but I cannot see which group I am from until I did the query above and saw the "1" as a result.

I needed to do the same and check if a certain User (using Windows Auth Login username) if what group he is from. He is just a common user so asking him to run my query is near impossible. thanks.

Comment: No way to figure this out? I really need the help, tried googling it and playing with sys tables. No luck. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For server roles (which your original question seemed you were after):

```
SELECT r.name 
  FROM sys.server_role_members AS m
  INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS l
    ON m.member_principal_id = l.principal_id
  INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS r
    ON m.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
  WHERE l.name = N'DOMAIN\Username';
  -----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ replace this part with your domain\user
```

For database roles:

```
SELECT r.name 
  FROM sys.database_role_members AS m
  INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dp
    ON m.member_principal_id = dp.principal_id
  INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS l
    ON dp.[sid] = l.[sid]
  INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS r
    ON m.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
  WHERE l.name = N'DOMAIN\Username';
  -----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ replace this part with your domain\user
```

Comment: Im sorry but it did not work for me. I got no results, if I remove the where clause I am getting 1 line with the l.name = 'sa'

Comment: You have beaten me by seconds to post almost exactly the same query - except for `WHERE r.type_desc LIKE N'%[_]ROLE'`. Is that part necessary? When joined from `server_role_members` on `role_principal_id` is it possible to have something else in `type_desc` other than `SERVER_ROLE`?

Comment: @Nenad I suppose not but it makes the intention of the query slightly more clear.

Comment: @Sid well you're going to have to explain a bit better which roles you're expecting to see and whether the windows auth users are members of those roles directly or through group membership. Basically you need to reverse engineer what is in sys.server_role_members and then how to map that to the login (or group).

Comment: Plus I am looking not in the server side, I tried IS_SRVROLEMEMBER but not knowing that is for server. I need to look for database, I replaced the sys.server_role_ etc to database_role... but it shows the group roles in our server. My main problem is to see if a certain Windows Auth Login is a member of that Group.

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for membership in ***database*** roles. Can you please update your question to state that? The use of `IS_{SERVER}ROLEMEMBER` led everyone in a different direction. Never mind, I've made it a bit more clear.